# Batch process with custom plugins in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, points-to-line

In QGIS, it is very easy to do batch processing like [this](https://docs.qgis.org/2.8/en/docs/user_manual/processing/batch.html) but how do you do run a batch process for a custom plugin?

More detail:

I have a number of point shapefiles and want to convert them to lines using the [Points2One](https://plugins.qgis.org/plugins/points2one/) tool and want to set up a batch process to run the plugin for each of my shapefiles (>100) in a given directory.

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2):

There are two possible tools in the toolbox, `v.to.lines` (GRASS) and `convert points to line(s)` (SAGA). Have you tried these? If so, what are they lacking?

Some plugins like `Quick OSM` can be incorporated into a graphical model, which in turn can be run as a batch process, maybe your tool shows up there, too.